# WebApp ARM template with variable number of AppSettings

Tags: json, azure-resource-manager

How can you create an ARM template for a web app that can take a varied number of App Settings in a parameters.json file?

I have tried using this approach:

```
{
  "name": "[concat(variables('web_app_name'), '/appsettings')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
  "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
  "properties": {
    "appSetting1": "value1",
    "AppSetting2": "value2"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('web_app_name'))]"
  ]
}
```

But this wipes my default properties on a WebApp such as APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY, ApplicationInsightsAgent_EXTENSION_VERSION etc. as this doesn't merge with the already existing app settings but overwrites them. There is an issue reported on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11718

Then there is some mentioning of using this method: https://kalcik.net/2019/11/21/merge-azure-app-service-app-settings-in-arm-template/

```
[union(
  variables('appServiceBaseConfig'), 
  variables('appService1'), 
  json(
    concat(
      '{\"APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY\":\"', 
      reference(concat('microsoft.insights/components/', variables('applicationInsightsName')), '2015-05-01').InstrumentationKey,
       '\"}')
    )
  )
]
```

but this makes my eyes bleed and doesn't even support line breaks and az deployment group validate pukes on it stating that it is not valid json if it is not on one line, which makes this useless.

Any smart work arounds?

Comment: Is it an option for you to use nested/linked ARM templates? I already used nested/linked templates, plus I use PowerShell to feed my parameters instead of parameters file. I solved the problem using a `union` but I do not need to use the `json(concat(...))` part.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Do you want to quote the parameter or variable in the config property? Or want to add the additional app settings without wiping the default settings?

Comment: @CharlesXu I want to add additional app settings without wiping the default settings.

Comment: @Stringfellow I can use nested templates but my main problem is how to provide a variable number of app settings to an ARM template for a WebApp.